# Почему save() срабытывает один раз?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть массив `$catID`.

**Вот его значения:**

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(1) "2"
     }
```

Пытаюсь запустить его для сохранения через foreach. **Вот код:**

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Serial();
    $category   = Category::find()->where('tags<>1')->all();
    $catSerial  =   new CatSerial();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
            $catID=$post['CatSerial']['id_cat'];
            $model->save();
        foreach($catID as $cat){
            $catSerial->id_cat=$cat;
            $catSerial->id_serial=$model->id;
            $catSerial->isNewRecord = true;
            $catSerial->save();
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model'     => $model,
            'category'  => $category,
            'catSerial' =>  $catSerial
        ]);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что `save()` отрабатывается один раз последний почему ? И как заставить работать дважды.

Comment: А `id_cat`  не автоинкремент? может попробовать `$catSerial->id_cat = NULL`?  либо вообще не писать `$catSerial->id_cat=$cat`

Comment: id_cat не авто инкремент это id сдругой таблицы

Comment: смотрите вот решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query вопрос в том как правильно activerecord запрос сделать такого типа INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )

Comment: Ну как вариант использовать `batchinsert` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#batchInsert()-detail  сформировав предварительно массив..... кроме того можно самому такой запрос с множеством `values` написать.... правда тоже через DAO

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да спасибо  Алексей можете оформлять ответ приму

Comment: Не не не, я экспериментировал.... вот теперь еще попрошу кое-что сделать. скорее всего `$catSerial->isNewRecord = true;` недостаточно, потому что генерируется один и тот же айдишник в первичного ключа.... у вас как он называется? Задайте ему специально значение `null`.... то есть допишите еще `$catSerial->id=null;` ..... где `id` - имя вашего `primary key` который с автоинкрементом...... вроде должно теперь сработать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне объяснили что обращение к базе в цикле признак говнокода поэтому через batchinsert

Comment: Это да, **но(!)** есть нюанс..... если использовать `pdo` и подготовленные выражения - то это вполне себе нормально.... т.е. сделать предварительно `prepare(MYSQL QUERY with params)` а затем в цикле фигачить `execute()`...т.к. запрос уже приготовлен .... `yii2` поддерживает `pdo` и подготовленные выражения..... только вот не знаю `save()` это тот самый `execute` или нет.....хотя лично я тоже всегда выступаю за `values values values` или правильно сделанный `select` нежели про кучу запросов в цикле...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы оформляете ответ? Если нет я сам его оформлю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save() в цикле работает не один раз а последний раз. Можно конечно обновить но обращаться к базе в цикле, не самый лучший вариант. Лучше всего использовать `batchinsert` пишу такой ответ сам поскольку
@АлексейШиманский отказался сам оформлять ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. Но, если у Вас много записей в цикле, то лучше использовать альтернативы, типа `batchinsert`, да.

```
foreach($catID as $cat){
    $catSerial = new CatSerial();
    $catSerial->id_cat=$cat;
    $catSerial->id_serial=$model->id;
    $catSerial->save();
}
```